# decomposing a group into a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question that I asked 2 days ago.
But it was not solved.....

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n ^*$ be the set of all units in $\mathbb{Z}_n$  and $(\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$ = $\{ a^2 | a \in \mathbb{Z}_n ^*\} $

Then,  decompose the factor group  $\mathbb{Z}_n ^* / (\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$

1. when $n$ is an odd prime
2. when $n$ is a product of two distinct odd primes $p, q$

I solved the first as following: In $\mathbb{Z}_p$, since $x^2=(p-x)^2$ holds, the order of $(\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$ is exactly the half of that of $\mathbb{Z}_n ^*$.

Thus, the answer is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

However the second is more complicated. I didn't know that. Please help me to solve this.